# How to manipulate the terminal output buffer directly

Tags: c++, c, linux, printing, terminal

I want to write a game in Linux terminal(In C/C++), so firstly I should be able to print the character I want to it. I tried with "printf()", but it seems a little inconvenient. I think there should be a character buffer for the output characters for a terminal. Is there any way to directly manipulate the buffer?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Why do you want to directly manipulate the buffer? Are you trying to get immediate output to the screen, perhaps?

Comment: you should look into ncurses for full terminal control as needed in games.

Comment: Hello, I mean I think the output of a terminal must be stored in some buffer, I'm wondering if there is a way to directly modify it. For example, suppose there's a character 'c' at position (2, 3) in the terminal window, and I want to change it to 'a'. This 'c' must be stored in some where in a buffer 'buf', let's say 'buf[2][3]'. I'm looking for a way to directly manipulate this 'buf' to modify 'buf[2][3]' from 'c' to 'a'. Is it clear for you?

Answer (score 4):

It goes in a way different manner.
A terminal is nothing else, but a character device, which means it is practically unbuffered. Despite of this, you still can manipulate the screen position with appropriate sequences of characters, called "escape sequences". For example, if you issue the \e[A (0x1B 0x91 0x41) sequence, the cursor goes one line up while leaving the characters intact, while if you issue \e[10;10H, (0x1B 0x91 0x31 0x30 0x3B 0x31 0x30 0x48), your cursor will go to column 10 of row 10 (exactly what you want). After you moved the cursor, the next character you write out goes to that position. For further information on escape sequences, look at [this link](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Another important thing to know about is the dimensions of your terminal. `ioctl` can inform you about the size of the terminal window:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
    struct winsize ws;
    ioctl (STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);
    printf ("Rows: %d, Cols: %d\n", ws.ws_row, ws.ws_col);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the technique mentioned above is a solution to send commands to the terminal emulator connected to your pseudo terminal device. That is, the terminal device itself remains unbuffered, the commands are interpreted by the terminal emulator.

Comment: Such as change the font and character size in the terminal? Can I manage that?

Comment: The link no longer works. This one does: https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01350-2e922997-2b8d-4599-a9fa-5a0698b9c035

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the [setbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setbuf) function, which allows you tell printf which buffer to be used. You can use your own buffer and control the contents.

However, this is the wrong approach for 2 reasons.

1st, it won't save you work compared to printf(), fwrite() and putchar().

2nd, and more important, even these functions won't help you. From your comment it's clear that you want to manipulate a character on the screen, for example, replace a '.' (empty floor) by a D (Dragon) when that Dragon approaches. You can't do this by manipulating the output buffer of printf(). Once the '.' is displayed, the output buffer has been flushed to the terminal, and if you manipulate that buffer, it has no effect. The terminal has received a copy of that buffer, and has displayed what the data in the buffer instructed it to display. In order to change what is displayed, you have to send new commands.

And this is exactly what [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) does for you. It keeps track of the state of the terminal, the current content, the curser position and all the nasty details, like, how to make a character appear bold.

You won't succeed with printf. That's hopeless. You need to learn what ncurses can do for you, and then everything else is easy.

Comment: As you've said above, the output buffer of 'printf()' will finally be flushed to terminal to display. And the terminal receives a copy of the buffer. So, can I locate that buffer in terminal(that receives the copy) and manipulate it directly? Is that what ncurses actually does?

Comment: No, you can't locate the buffer in the terminal. The terminal eats up the data it receives, interprets the data as instructions, and then the data is gone. After that, the only thing you can do is send more data to the terminal, sending new instructions. And this is what ncurses does for you.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: use `ncurses`

---

This answer focuses on the **why?**

---

### Why?

There probably is a way to modify the buffer used by the **terminal emulator** on your system, given that you have sufficient priviledges to write into respective memory and maybe even modify other system resources, as required.

As [terminals historically have been distinct, isolated, physical devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) rather than [beeing conceptually emulated in software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), you couldn't access them in any way other than sending them data.

(I mean, you could always print a message locally, to instruct a human to take a screwdriver and physically mess around with the physical terminal device, but that's not been the way how humans wanted to solve the contemporary issue of "how do I change the cursor position and rewrite characters on my (and potentially any other connected) terminal?").

As others have pointed out, most physical terminals have (at some point) been built to give special meaning to certain input sequences, instead of printing them, which makes them [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) in this context, according to how wikipedia.org defines them, that is.

A behavioral convention in how to respond to certain input sequences emerged (presumably for the sake of interoperability or for reasons of market predominance)
and got standardized as [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Those input sequences survived the transition from physical termial devices to their emulated counterparts and even though you could probably manipulate the terminal emulator's memory using system calls, libraries such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) allow you to easily make use of said [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in your console application.

### Also, using such libraries is the obvious solution to make your application work remotely:

Yes, technically, you could `ssh` into another system (or get access in any other more obscure way that works for you),
and cause system calls or any other event that would interfere with the terminal emulator in the desired way.

- Firstly, I doubt most users would want to grant you priviledge to modify their terminal emulator's memory merely to enjoy your text adventure.
- Also, interoperability would reduce, as you couldn't easily support that one user, who still has a [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) and insists on using it to play your game.

Comment: And yet, while this answer offers the *historical* justification for why things are what they are, the terminal emulator itself DOES have a screen buffer of one form or another, where it renders the contents to , according to its received commands. Maybe for the purpose of a game, the question could be of interest, how to replicate that part of a terminal emulator. Would be useful if that part were contained in a library, not?!